# Is there an easy way to find theta from any X and Y position along a circle?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any single formula that is able to calculate theta from any relative X and Y position, negative inclusive?

Take the following points from the unit circle for instance:

```
 X = sqrt(3)/2, Y = 1/2 -> 30°
 X = -sqrt(3)/2, Y = 1/2 -> 150°
 X = -sqrt(3)/2, Y = -1/2 -> 210°
 X = sqrt(3)/2, Y = -1/2 -> 330°
```

Is there any one formula that will determine theta, including negative values for X an Y?

The code below is a solution to my problem, but I'm looking for a cleaner formula.

```
// Find theta from X and Y
double deg;
if (X >= 0 && Y >= 0) { // QUADRANT I
    deg = atan(Y / X) * 180 / M_PI;
} else if (X <= 0 && Y >= 0) { // QUADRANT II
    deg = abs(atan(Y / -X) * 180 / M_PI - 90) + 90;
} else if (X <= 0 && Y <= 0) { // QUADRANT III
    deg = abs(atan(-Y / -X) * 180 / M_PI) + 180;
} else { // QUADRANT IV
    deg = abs(atan(-Y / X) * 180 / M_PI - 90) + 270;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) (which really just sweeps the if-then clutter under a named rug, but should be available in most programming languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programming languages have a function called `atan2` that takes two arguments, e.g. `atan2(x,y)` gives the angle formed by the coordinate $(x,y)$.  If your programming language doesn't have this, then you can implement it fairly simply as follows:

1. If `x = 0`, let `theta = 90 * (2 - sign(y))`, where `sign(y)` is the sign of `y`.  Note that this assumes that if $x = 0$ then $y \ne 0$.
2. Otherwise, let `theta = mod(atan(y/x) + 90 * (1 - sign(x)), 360)` where `mod` is the remainder function.  Note that this assumes that `atan` returns an angle strictly between `-90` and `90`.

If you do not have the `mod` function or it doesn't work for non-integer values, then you need an additional step, which is to let `a = atan(y/x) + 90 * (1 - sign(x))`, then:

3. If `a < 0`, then `theta = a + 360`, otherwise `theta = a`.

Comment: Quite a few languages flip the order of arguments to `atan2`, i.e. `atan(y, x)` (probably to keep the order from `atan(y/x)`). It’s something to look out for; check your documentation.